# Show a matrix is similar to a lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}2 & -1 \\0 & 2\end{array}\right)$

$B = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda & 0 \\1 & \lambda\end{array}\right)$.

I know that the $\lambda = 2$. And $r(1,0)^t$, where $r \in $ Reals are the eigenvectors.

How do you show, via calculation, that $A$ is similar to $B$?

Note: If two matrices are similar, then there is a third matrix $C$, such that $B = C^{-1}AC$.

Answer (score 1):

That means find an invertible matrix $P$ with 
\begin{align}
B = P^{-1} A P \iff \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0 \\
1 & \lambda
\end{array}
\right) 
&=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
d & -b \\
-c  & a
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -1 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
d & -b \\
-c  & a
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2a-c & 2b-d \\
2c & 2d
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2(ad-bc) - cd & -d^2 \\
c^2 & 2(ad-bc) + cd
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
Comparing components, we take $d=0$ and continue with
\begin{align}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 0 \\
1 & \lambda
\end{array}
\right) 
&=
\frac{1}{-bc}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-2bc & 0 \\
c^2 & -2bc
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
-c/b & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\end{align}
So we can pick any $a$, any $b \ne 0$ and then choose $c = -b$ and $d = 0$.
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b \\
-b & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\quad
P^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1/b \\
1/b & a/b^2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For example
$$
P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\quad
P^{-1} =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
should do the job of making $B$ similar to $A$.
\begin{align}
P^{-1} A P 
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -1 \\
0 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) \\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 2 \\
-2 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 0 \\
1 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
\\
&=
B
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Finding the transpose of an upper triangular matrix will render it similar to a lower triangular matrix, as introduced by British mathematician Arthur Cayley.

Let $\mathbf U$ be an upper triangular matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & \cdots & a_{1,n-1} & a_{1n} \\
0 & a_{22} & a_{23} & \cdots & a_{2,n-1} & a_{2n} \\
0 & 0 & a_{33} & \cdots & a_{3,n-1} & a_{3n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_{n-1,n-1} & a_{n-1,n} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & a_{nn} \\
\end{bmatrix}

By definition:

$$\forall a_{ij} \in \mathbf U: i > j \implies a_{ij} = 0$$

We can let $\mathbf{U}^T$ be the transpose of $\mathbf{U}$, so $\mathbf U^\intercal = \left[{b}\right]_n: \forall i \in \left[{1 \,.\,.\, n}\right], j \in \left[{1 \,.\,.\, n}\right]: b_{i j} = a_{j i}$

From this, we get:

$$\forall b_{ji} \in \mathbf U^\intercal: i > j \implies b_{ji} = 0$$

Then, exchange $i$ and $j$ in the notation above to get:

$$\forall b_{ij} \in \mathbf U^\intercal: i < j \implies b_{ij} = 0$$

Use this theorem to show how matrix $A$ is similar to matrix $B$.